# How to plot POSIXct objects / timestamps independent of day?

Tags: r, datetime, plot, posixct

I hope the question title makes sense. I am collecting some data using a Google Form. The form is always submitted between 5 and 7 pm but on different days. I want to plot the `time` component of the timestamp on the x-axis versus some other value from the form. I want to make sure that all time plots end up in the same two-hour window in the plot (i.e., between 5 and 7pm) regardless of the `date` component of the timestamp.

I have downloaded the responses as a CSV and can read in the timestamps without any issues:

`demo <- as.POSIXct(demo$Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

And the data looks like this:

```
> demo
 [1] "2015-10-12 17:02:42 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:02:46 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:02:46 CEST"
 [4] "2015-10-12 17:02:50 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:02:52 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:02:55 CEST"
 [7] "2015-10-12 17:02:58 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:03:02 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:03:09 CEST"
[10] "2015-10-12 17:03:15 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:03:22 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:03:24 CEST"
[13] "2015-10-12 17:03:36 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:03:48 CEST" "2015-10-12 17:04:07 CEST"
[16] "2015-10-12 17:09:20 CEST"
```

I can plot these using something as simple as this:

```
plot(demo, rnorm(length(demo)))
```

But I want the range on the x-axis to be 5-7pm and I need to make sure that all data is plotted in that two-hour range, independent on the day the data was recorded at. If I do something like this:

```
startTime <- as.POSIXct("17:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")
endTime <- as.POSIXct("19:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")
plot(demo, rnorm(length(demo)), xlim=c(startTime, endTime), xaxt='n')
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(startTime, endTime, by="hour"), format = "%M", labels=c("17:00", "18:00", "19:00"))
```

I get the right outline for the plot but no data. This is because `startTime` and `endTime` will be set to the current date. If I explicitly use make them the same date as the data in `demo` ...

```
startTime <- as.POSIXct("10/12/2015 17:00:00", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
endTime <- as.POSIXct("10/12/2015 19:00:00", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

... the data shows up in the plot exactly the way I want them to.

**However: I can't add data points from any other day.** Can someone explain to me how I can manipulate/use POSIXct objects to strip them of their "date" component and plot them in the same plot?

---

For testing purposes, you can copy this vector to reproduce the code I posted above:

```
demo <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-12 17:02:42 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:46 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:46 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:50 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:52 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:55 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:02:58 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:02 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:09 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:15 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:22 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:24 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:36 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:03:48 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:04:07 CEST", "2015-10-12 17:09:20 CEST"))
```

Comment: I would hack it with regex `demo[grepl("1[789](?=:\\d{2}:)", demo, perl=T)]`. But you can try to work with `lubridate` or `chron` or another hour minute formatting method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try getting the hours and minutes out using lubridate, then reformatting back to POSIXct. This will work as the default origin for POSIXct is the current date.

```
library(lubridate)
demo <- as.POSIXct(paste(hour(demo), minute(demo)), format = "%H %M")
```

Comment: Ahh, this is perfect. That way, I can *convert* all my times to "today" and they all show up in the same two-hour window. I am a little mad that I didn't think of this myself - thank you very much for your help!